# Groupby Aggregate method is returning NaN always

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am running into this issue where my datasource events looks like this:

```
   event_id             device_id            timestamp  longitude  latitude
0         1     29182687948017175  2016-05-01 00:55:25     121.38     31.24
1         2  -6401643145415154744  2016-05-01 00:54:12     103.65     30.97
2         3  -4833982096941402721  2016-05-01 00:08:05     106.60     29.7
```

I am trying to group the events by the device_id and then get the sum/mean/std of the variable over every event with that device_id:

```
events['latitude_mean'] = events.groupby(['device_id'])['latitude'].aggregate(np.sum)
```

But my Output is always:

```
event_id             device_id            timestamp  longitude  latitude
0         1     29182687948017175  2016-05-01 00:55:25     121.38     31.24   
1         2  -6401643145415154744  2016-05-01 00:54:12     103.65     30.97   
2         3  -4833982096941402721  2016-05-01 00:08:05     106.60     29.70   
3         4  -6815121365017318426  2016-05-01 00:06:40     104.27     23.28   
4         5  -5373797595892518570  2016-05-01 00:07:18     115.88     28.66   

   latitude_mean  
0            NaN  
1            NaN  
2            NaN  
3            NaN  
4            NaN
```

What am I doing wrong to keep getting the return value to be NaN for each row?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform(aggfunc)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) method, which applies `aggfunc` to all rows in each group:

```
In [32]: events['latitude_mean'] = events.groupby(['device_id'])['latitude'].transform('sum')

In [33]: events
Out[33]:
   event_id            device_id            timestamp  longitude  latitude  latitude_mean
0         1    29182687948017175  2016-05-01 00:55:25     121.38     31.24          62.55
1         2    29182687948017175  2016-05-30 12:12:12     777.77     31.31          62.55
2         3 -6401643145415154744  2016-05-01 00:54:12     103.65     30.97          64.30
3         4 -6401643145415154744  2016-01-01 11:11:11     111.11     33.33          64.30
```

[Here you may find some usage examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation)

**Explanation:** when you group your DF - as a result you usually have a series containing less rows and with different index, so pandas doesn't know how to align it when assigning it to a new column and as a result you have NaN's:

```
In [31]: events.groupby(['device_id'])['latitude'].agg(np.sum)
Out[31]:
device_id
-6401643145415154744    64.30
 29182687948017175      62.55
Name: latitude, dtype: float64
```

so when you try to assign it to a new column, pandas does something like this:

```
In [36]: events['nans'] = pd.Series([1,2], index=['a','b'])

In [38]: events[['event_id','nans']]
Out[38]:
   event_id  nans
0         1   NaN
1         2   NaN
2         3   NaN
3         4   NaN
```

Data:

```
In [30]: events
Out[30]:
   event_id            device_id            timestamp  longitude  latitude
0         1    29182687948017175  2016-05-01 00:55:25     121.38     31.24
1         2    29182687948017175  2016-05-30 12:12:12     777.77     31.31
2         3 -6401643145415154744  2016-05-01 00:54:12     103.65     30.97
3         4 -6401643145415154744  2016-01-01 11:11:11     111.11     33.33
```

Comment: PRs for great documentation (or even a minimal docstring :-)) is always welcome!

Comment: @joris, yeah, fair enough... :)